# java 8 Swing application with oracle 10 g database

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I created one Swing project in Java 8 and I used Oracle 10g for database connectivity. Everything is fine but when I run my project then after few operations i am getting following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found
The Connection descriptor used by the client was:
localhost:1521:xe
```

I have used following query in oracle database :-

```
alter system set processes=300 scope=spfile;
```

But it's not working still number of processes is 40:-

```
RESOURCE_NAME                processes
CURRENT_UTILIZATION          39
MAX_UTILIZATION              40
INITIAL_ALLOCATION           40
LIMIT_VALUE                  40
```

What should I do?

Hello I am using following code for connection:-

package connection;

import java.sql.*;

public class conn  {

```
Connection con;
Statement st;
ResultSet rs;



public ResultSet GetData(String s) {

    try{

        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "system", "123456");
        st=con.createStatement();
        //System.out.println("Connected to DataBase to show the result...");
        rs=st.executeQuery(s);

    }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
        System.out.println(e);
                    }
        return rs;

        }



public void UpdateData(String s) {

    try
    {
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
    con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE", "system", "123456");
    st=con.createStatement();
    //System.out.println("Connected to the DataBase for Updating the Record...");
    st.executeUpdate(s);
    System.out.println("Record Updated...");


    }

    catch(Exception e1)
    {
    System.out.println(e1); 
    }


}
```

}

These codes are in seperate class now when ever i want to use the database connectivity in project i am just creating a object of this class and using a functions.
In my project i am using timer as well to refresh data of JTable. Please kindly provide solution ?

Comment: Hi, are you opening new connections without closing previous opened?

Comment: can you share complete java code for database connection ?

Comment: Please edit your question so that 1. the title actual summarizes the problem, and 2. include your code and the full exception stracktrace.

Comment: You might not be allowed to tweak the numbers of parallel processes/connections in Oracle XE which is a free version. But if you have a single-workstation Swing application, you probably don't need more available connections, you just need to manage resources correctly. Just wrapping your data access code within a try-with-resources clause might fix this for you. But we can't know without seeing code.

Comment: The database must be restarted for the new processes parameter to take effect.

Comment: Hello @JonHeller Every time when i run this project then i restart the oracle but still i am getting same error.

Comment: @Navneet The value of PROCESSES stays set to 40 even after a restart?

Comment: Yes it's still 40. I have run the following command many times:- alter system set processes=300 scope=spfile; after this i restarted the oracle. but still processes stays set to 40.

Comment: Its Resolved now. Thank You so much to all for your support. It was happening because i didn't create connection in database connectivity class which i have mentioned in my question and codes. every time when timer start then it creates new instance of database connectivity class without closing old one. Now i created closed method in the connection class and every thing is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Its Resolved now. Thank You so much to all for your support. It was happening because i didn't close connection in database connectivity class which i have mentioned in my question and codes. every time when timer start then it creates new instance of database connectivity class without closing old one. Now i created close method in the connection class and every thing is fine.